# Redirect all web requests

Tags: unix, redirect, proxy

my goal is simple. I have primary and backup links. The policy is that guest users can only works over primary link. When it goes down, BGP doesnt advertise default route for guests over backup link. They have access to dns. I want the guests to see my custom webpage telling them that internet is not working and they shoul wait. What app can I use? Squid? Furthermore In case there is no defualt route from bgp I can set defaul route to some unix machine. Thank you

Comment: What does "BGP" refer to here?

Comment: Hi. It is for dynamic routing